# C++ Unique values in a vector?

Tags: c++, vector, unique

I have to create a program which asks the user to enter 20 numbers between 10 and 100 which will be stored in a vector, but only unique values will be stored. I have created a program which stores the values within the range, but I don't  know how to store only the unique values. Here is what I have:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

void print(vector<int>v);

int main()
{
    vector<int>v;


    int x;
    for (int num = 0; num < 20; num++)
    {
        cout << "Enter number " << (num + 1) << ":";
        cin >> x;
        if (10 < x)
        {
            if (x < 100)

                v.push_back(x);
        }
    }
    print(v);


}

void print(vector<int>v2)
{
    for (int count = 0; count < v2.size(); count++)
    cout << v2[count] << " ";
}
```

Comment: Why does your print version copy the whole vector? That is unnecessary. Pass by const reference instead.

Comment: If vector must be used, then use `std::find` function to check if the value already exists before inserting.

Comment: why don't you just use a std::set?

Comment: The simplest thing is to just iterate through the vector and if you find the value, set a flag.   After, if the flag isn't set then add it.  But if this weren't homework then you wouldn't use a vector for this.   Makes no sense.

Answer (score 12):

You can use `std::unique`:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/unique/?kw=unique

```
using namespace std;

vector<int> v;
int x;

for (int num = 0; num < 20; num++)
{
    cout << "Enter number " << (num + 1) << ":";
    cin >> x;
    if (10 < x)
    {
        if (x < 100)

            v.push_back(x);
    }
}

sort(v.begin(), v.end());
vector<int>::iterator it;
it = unique(v.begin(), v.end());  

v.resize(distance(v.begin(),it));
```

Comment: Although the linked page makes it clear, it might be worth mentioning here that the use of sort requires `#include <algorithm>`, and distance requires `#include <iterator>`

Comment: I'd say that `v.erase(std::unique(v.begin(), v.end()), v.end)` is more idiomatic than the `v.resize()` call.

Answer (score 4):

You could use a `std::set` or `std::unordered_set` to track the values you have already seen. Specifically the `insert` method will return whether the value has already been inserted into the set. Then you only push the value into the vector if the value is new.

Answer (score 2):

My solution, below, attempts to change the code as little as possible (added 4 lines). I have run this on the command line.

Note that right after the statement 'cin >> x', I added a test to determine if the integer entered was already in the vector v. If the test succeeds, then the possible addition of the entered integer to the vector is abandoned, with similar impact to its being out of range.

Note, also, that `<algorithm>` must be included to use find.

Being just a wee bit rusty, I did a quick search online, using 'c++ vector test membership' (without the quotes, of course :-) as a search term.

I assumed that performance is not yet a priority issue, but if the vector size were much larger than 20, it might be worth a hash (there are apparently comparable `<algorithm>` variants), giving more of a log(n) search time than a linear search time.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

void print(vector<int>v);

int main()
{
    vector<int>v;


    int x;
    for (int num = 0; num < 20; num++)
    {
        cout << "Enter number " << (num + 1) << ":";
        cin >> x;
        if (find(v.begin(), v.end(), x) != v.end()) {
            continue;
        }
        if (10 < x)
        {
            if (x < 100)

                v.push_back(x);
        }
    }
    print(v);


}

void print(vector<int>v2)
{
    for (int count = 0; count < v2.size(); count++)
    cout << v2[count] << " ";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**SIMPLE:**

```
sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());
vec.erase(unique(vec.begin(), vec.end()), vec.end());
```

Comment: Though we thank you for your answer, it would be better if it provided additional value on top of the other answers. In this case, your answer does not provide additional value, since [another answer](/a/26826258/4850040) already contains that solution. If a previous answer was helpful to you, you should vote it up instead of repeating the same information.

Answer (score 0):

Read the values into a ***set***, and create the vector from that (if you can't change the consumer to accept a different container):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <vector>

void print(std::vector<int> const& v)
{
    for (auto val: v) {
        std::cout << val << " ";
    }
}

int main()
{
    // read into a set
    std::set<int> s;
    for (int num = 0;  num < 20;  ++num) {
        std::cout << "Enter number " << (num + 1) << ": ";
        int x;
        std::cin >> x;
        if (10 < x && x < 100) {
            s.insert(x);
        }
    }

    // create vector from the set
    std::vector<int> v(s.begin(), s.end());

    print(v);
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```